# Coherence Distributed Cache Expiry Delay

Tags: caching, oracle-coherence

I have the below config for my coherence server.  What's the default expiry delay and eviction policy?  And how do I modify the default settings?

```
<cache-config>
    <caching-scheme-mapping>
        <cache-mapping>
            <cache-name>TEST_CACHE</cache-name>
            <scheme-name>distributed-extend</scheme-name>
        </cache-mapping>
    </caching-scheme-mapping>

    <caching-schemes>
        <distributed-scheme>
            <scheme-name>distributed-extend</scheme-name>
            <service-name>DistributedCache</service-name>
            <lease-granularity>member</lease-granularity>
            <backing-map-scheme>
                <local-scheme/>
            </backing-map-scheme>
            <autostart>true</autostart>
        </distributed-scheme>
        <proxy-scheme>
            <service-name>ExtendTcpProxyService</service-name>
            <thread-count>5</thread-count>
            <acceptor-config>
            <tcp-acceptor>
                <local-address>
                    <address>localhost</address>
                    <port>9098</port>
                </local-address>
            </tcp-acceptor>
            </acceptor-config>
            <autostart>true</autostart>
        </proxy-scheme>
    </caching-schemes>
</cache-config>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default is never, equivalent to

```
<expiry-delay>0</expiry-delay>
```

[see local-scheme expiry-delay](http://coherence.oracle.com/display/COH34UG/local-scheme#local-scheme-expirydelay)

Along with the expiration you better set  to optimize entries eviction. 
[see local-scheme flush-delay](http://coherence.oracle.com/display/COH34UG/local-scheme#local-scheme-flushdelay)

In your example instead of `<local-scheme/>` 
do something like

```
<local-scheme>
  <expiry-delay>10d</expiry-delay>
  <flush-delay>1d</flush-delay>
</local-scheme>
```

it means that coherence will evict entries 10 days old once a day

Comment: Hi, I am wondering when will this entry <expiry-delay> be used? We updated our config file with this entry however the cache entry remained in the cache after the specified time. Should we use the "put" method which takes CacheMap.EXPIRY_DEFAULT as a third parameter?

Comment: did you stop yuor cluster entirely after the change?

Comment: Yes we did, still didn't work. We are running it in WeBlogic12c